# Logic for UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to make a typical situation: when user selects any cell, it's accessoryType turns in checkmark. Only one cell's accessoryType can be checkmark. And then I wanna save in NSUserDefaults indexPath.row so my app will be able to know which cell user selected and make some changes in options. So I wrote this wrong code:

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // checkedIndexPath is NSIndexPath

    if(self.checkedIndexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                        cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
        uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.checkedIndexPath.row]forKey:@"indexpathrow" ];
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Part of code from cellForRowAtIndexPath

    if(indexPath.row == [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"indexpathrow"]intValue ])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

        return cell;
}
```

However, this code works badly. When you open the `UITableView`, there is an already selected cell in the table and when you press another there are two `checkmarked` cells...How can I improve my code or should I change it whole ? Any suggestions ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // checkedIndexPath is NSIndexPath
    NSIndexPath *previousSelection = self.checkedIndexPath;
    NSArray *array = nil;
    if (nil != previousSelection) {
        array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:previousSelection, indexPath, nil];
    } else {
        array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    }

    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Part of code from cellForRowAtIndexPath
    NSString *cellID = @"CellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
        [cell autorelease];
    }

// some code for initializing cell content
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if(self.checkedIndexPath != nil && indexPath.row == self.checkedIndexPath.row)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Question: It seems that willSelectRowAtIndexPath method type is not void but NSIndexPath, so it asks me to return a NSIndexPath. What should I return ? Thanks !

Comment: @SmartTree From the docs: An index-path object that confirms or alters the selected row. Return an NSIndexPath object other than indexPath if you want another cell to be selected. Return nil if you don't want the row selected.

Comment: @SmartTree, I've updated code-snippet for proper return in willSelect... method

Comment: why do you do this in `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Denis, thanks for your response. I used your code but when I move to tableView there is an already selected (checkmarked) cell and when I press another cell there are two selected cells now and if I press this cell again, app crashes with this log:
'Attempt to create two animations for cell'

Do I do something wrong ? I am trying to find an error...

Comment: @SmartTree, I've updated code in the answer - i have missed the 'self.checkedIndexPath != nil' check, so it was a bug in the logic.

Comment: Works perfectly now ! Thank you !
But how can I save the result (checked cell ) to NSUserDefaults, so my app will be able to do some things which depends on that result ? Thanks !

Comment: add the following line at the end of didSelectRowAtIndexPath: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]forKey:@"indexpathrow" ];

Comment: Yes, thanks, and How can I read this NSUserDefaults when tableView appears and put checkmark on the cell which was selected ? For example: user selected a cell and closed the app. Then he returns to the tableView and see that cell he selected is selected. Sorry, that I ask you too many questions.