# UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark issue, many cells get checked by only checking one row

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableview` with many rows, approx 60 rows, and I want the user to be able to `check` or `uncheck` with a `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` as many rows as he wants. The problem is that when I check a certain `cell`, all the other cells in that position will be checked too. For example if I check the row number 5, the row number 15,25,35 and so on will get a `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` too, and I don't want that to happen. I need that the rows checked be only the ones that the user really selected. Here is my code for the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    Materia *current = [Manejador MateriasEnListaAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
    if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [ManejadorVistas EliminarMateria:current];
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [ManejadorVistas AgregarMateria:current];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is due to the cell reusing mechanism. Cell hasn't been reused properly. Post your cellForRowAtIndexPath Code also.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814060/check-uncheck-buttons-in-uitableviews-cell/12814962#12814962

Comment: see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622102/logic-for-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark

Answer (score 1):

set `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`  to `nil` like bellow and then try to use it...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

also write your code in this bellow condition..

```
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

     // write your code here....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

     // write your code here....
}
Materia *current = [Manejador MateriasEnListaAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

//While reusing we have to check whether ManejadorVistas contains the object. 
//Because you would have added it inside didSelect Delegate

if([ManejadorVistas containsObject:current]) 
{
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```